# Обрезать фото(thumb) для товаров в интернет магазине

Tags: php

Всем привет. При добавлении товара обрезаю фотографию. Использую библиотеку `SimpleImage.php` Инструкция по библиотеке [тута](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)

```
$img_test = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($uploadfile);
$img_test->thumbnail(270, 180);
$img_test->save($uploadthumb);
```

Но есть один неприятный момент. Если брать абсолютно любую фотографию, например квадратную 800 на 800, то он создает thumb размером 270 на 180, но при этому обрезает часть верхней фото. Как вы выкручиваетесь из этой ситуации? как вообще правильно создавать thumb фото для интернет магазина?

Comment: Как вы хотите из квадратного изображения получить прямоугольную превьюшку и ни чего не обрезать?

Comment: ну типо как в инстаграм. Instagram при публикации фотографий переделывает прямоугольные изображения в квадратные. Причем он не просто обрезает их, а дополняет по краям белым фоном, чтобы получилось квадратное фото.

Comment: У этой библиотеки видимо нет такой функции.